# Kohana ORM плюсы и минусы

Tags: orm, php, kohana

Используете ли Вы в своих проектах ORM?

Да? Что полезного или удобного Вы нашли для себя?

Нет? Считаете что от ORM больше вреда чем пользы?

Answer (score 2):

Очень часто использую [ORM](https://github.com/kohana/orm), встроенный в Kohana. До этого было время, когда надо было применять [RedBean](http://redbeanphp.com/). С монстрами вроде [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) еще не связывался.

Т.к. никаких high-load проектов я не разрабатываю, то **считаю применение ORM оправданным**. Скорость разработки вырастает в разы за счёт простого добавления новых сущностей, связей и работы со всем этим.

Иногда, когда надо выполнить сложный запрос, приходится писать не самые красивые конструкции, т.к. **не хватает гибкости модуля** *(или ума?)*

Скорее всего страдает скорость работы, но, опять же, **надо оценивать требования**.

RedBean же периодически использую для каких-либо очень простых/игрушечных проектов, т.к. она **сама генерирует структуру БД** и позволяет думать только о идее.